# Selenium Webdriver with Python - Not able to give input (Date) in a web application using Selenium Web driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm not sure how to input a date in an datefield in an web application using Selenium Webdriver with python. I have tried this below code.

```
driver.find_elements_by_name("invDate")[0].click()
```

which brings the cursor in that date field box. Now here I'm not sure how to give date by typing in this datefield.

Any help on how to pass the date for example (04/14/2019) value to this datefield box where the cursor is current placing would be really beneficial.

Thanks.

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to format it. In question (not in comment) add url to this page.

Comment: `send_keys(...)`

Comment: Hi Furas,
Send_keys is not working for me..can you please explain a bit elaborting pls

Comment: as I said before - put URL in question - and then we can see this element and search solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide a brief description and at-least a screenshot.

As per your question, I can guess you have already opened the date-field box and now you need to add date in it.

To enter text into the Text Fields, **send_keys()** is the function, which need to be used:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('your_element_name').send_keys("04/14/2019")
```